Power BI Desktop figures not equal in published in Workspace
I am working on a visual that reflects the following in Power BI desktop.

However, when I uploaded it in the workspace (no saved bookmarks and no applied filters), the below reflects:

Value is a normalization saved in Sharepoint while the count came from a direct query table from Snowflake. Any idea what happened here?
I have tried recreating the report with a new file but to no avail.
